# How to assign a set value to a column if a condition is met?

Tags: python, pandas, bigdata

I have a set of products that I need to assign google taxonomy codes to. All up there is roughly 213000 products I need to add these codes to. I have entered a small sample of 7000 into pandas to see if I can write something to run off keywords and assign a code to a column if the keyword is in found.

I am still getting my head around Python & Pandas in general.

I thought if I write an if statement declaring that if it met a keyword write the taxonomy code to the googlecode column for every row that contained the keyword that would work. But I have no idea how to write the thing. I have tried a few variations and keep hitting a wall. Any advice where to start would be great, even tutorial recommendations on how to do something like this.

My code currently is as follows:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
product_data = pd.read_csv(
    r'C:\Users\mathewo\Documents\Python\Google sheet match.csv',
    dtype={
        'productcode': 'string',
        'category': 'string'
        }
    )
        
product_data.dropna(inplace = True)
        
product_data["googlecode"] = ""
        
        
brake_code = [2977]
mirror_code = [2642]
generic_code = [5613]
lights_code = [3318]
suspension_code = [2935]
tyres_code = [911]
        
        
if product_data['category'].str.contains('BRAKE').any():
    product_data['googlecode'].string.contains('BRAKE').any = brake_code
```

Current book:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
conditions=['BRAKE','MIRROR','GENRIC','LIGHTS','SUSPENSION','TYRES']
labels=[2977,2642,5613,3318,2935,911]
```

Finally use `str.extract()` and `map()`:

```
pat='('+'|'.join(conditions)+')'
product_data['googlecode']=product_data['category'].str.extract(pat,expand=False)
product_data['googlecode']=product_data['googlecode'].map(dict(zip(conditions,labels)))
```

Comment: @Erfan you are right sir.....thanks sir for the suggestion **:)**

Comment: @Anurag Dabas you need to surround your `A|B|C` regex with parentheses `(A|B|C)` or there won't be any capture group. Also, you can directly create the dictionary and use it in your join as the keys will be used. Here is a simplified version: `codes = {'BRAKE': 2977,  'MIRROR': 2642,  'GENRIC': 5613,  'LIGHTS': 3318,  'SUSPENSION': 2935,  'TYRES': 911} ; product_data['googlecode']=product_data['category'].str.extract('(%s)' %'|'.join(codes),expand=False).map(codes)`

Comment: @mozway you are right sir.....thanks sir for the suggestion..made changes in answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Imagine this input dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'productcode': ['AA7690', 'AB0105', 'XYZ123', 'ZZ5103'],
                   'category': ['TRUCK & TAILER, AIR SYSTEM, ', 'TRUCK & TAILER, AIR SYSTEM, ', 'BLAHBLAH BRAKE BLAH', 'ACCESSORIES, BRANDED MERCHANDISE']
                   })
```

```
  productcode                          category
0      AA7690      TRUCK & TAILER, AIR SYSTEM, 
1      AB0105      TRUCK & TAILER, AIR SYSTEM, 
2      XYZ123               BLAHBLAH BRAKE BLAH
3      ZZ5103  ACCESSORIES, BRANDED MERCHANDISE
```

You can use this custom function to search for product codes and append them as a new column

```
import re
codes = {'BRAKE': 2977, 'TRUCK': 1234, 'MIRROR': 2642}
regex_code = re.compile('|'.join(codes))
def search(s):
    m = regex_code.search(s)
    if m and m.group() in codes:
        return codes[m.group()]
    return 0
df['googlecode'] = df.category.apply(search)
```

output:

```
  productcode                          category  googlecode
0      AA7690      TRUCK & TAILER, AIR SYSTEM,         1234
1      AB0105      TRUCK & TAILER, AIR SYSTEM,         1234
2      XYZ123               BLAHBLAH BRAKE BLAH        2977
3      ZZ5103  ACCESSORIES, BRANDED MERCHANDISE           0
```

if you prefer to have NaNs rather than 0 when there is no match, remove the `return 0` in the function